# Django Admin list_display user not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, dashboard

basically this is my admin.py:

```
class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['offer_number', 'address', 'estate', 'city', 'date', 
'price', 'status', 'user']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
       if not obj.user:
          obj.user = request.user
       super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

im just making a normal list_display which works fine besides user, with user i want it to be automatic, what i mean by automatic is that i want for me to go into my admin dashboard and go to my model(Property) then after that i add properties everything works until we get to user in user there is a dropdown menu where i can choose from all the users registered. Well what i want is for me to go and add the property and then when i save it automatically adds my username under 'user' or whoever made it. If anyone could suggest anything it would help a lot. thx

i tried looking everywhere and asking chatgpt